# Check if a string contains another string

Tags: string, vba

I want to find if a string contains a ","(comma) in it. Do we have any other option other than reading char-by-char?

Comment: Does `INSTR` work for you?

Answer (score 445, accepted):

Use the [Instr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) function (old version of MSDN doc found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264811(v=office.14).aspx))

```
Dim pos As Integer

pos = InStr("find the comma, in the string", ",")
```

will return 15 in pos

**If not found it will return 0**

If you need to find the comma with an excel formula you can use the `=FIND(",";A1)` function.

Notice that if you want to use `Instr` to find the position of a string case-insensitive use the third parameter of Instr and give it the const `vbTextCompare` (or just 1 for die-hards).

```
Dim posOf_A As Integer

posOf_A = InStr(1, "find the comma, in the string", "A", vbTextCompare)
```

will give you a value of 14.

Note that you have to specify the start position in this case as stated in the specification I linked: *The start argument is required if compare is specified.*

Comment: But what if the found string is in position 0? How do you distinguish between "found on index 0" and "not found (0)"?

Comment: @gEdringer. When the string to be found is at the start it returns 1.

Answer (score 82):

You can also use the special word `like`:

```
Public Sub Search()
  If "My Big String with, in the middle" Like "*,*" Then
    Debug.Print ("Found ','")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Link to pattern format https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 25):

There is also the [InStrRev](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251545%28v=office.14%29.aspx) function which does the same type of thing, but starts searching from the end of the text to the beginning.

Per @rene's answer...

```
Dim pos As Integer
pos = InStrRev("find the comma, in the string", ",")
```

...would still return 15 to pos, but if the string has more than one of the search string, like the word "the", then:

```
Dim pos As Integer
pos = InStrRev("find the comma, in the string", "the")
```

...would return 20 to pos, instead of 6.

Answer (score 19):

Building on Rene's answer, you could also write a function that returned either TRUE if the substring was present, or FALSE if it wasn't:

```
Public Function Contains(strBaseString As String, strSearchTerm As String) As Boolean
'Purpose: Returns TRUE if one string exists within another
On Error GoTo ErrorMessage
    Contains = InStr(strBaseString, strSearchTerm)
Exit Function
ErrorMessage:
MsgBox "The database has generated an error. Please contact the database administrator, quoting the following error message: '" & Err.Description & "'", vbCritical, "Database Error"
End
End Function
```

Comment: What kind of a database error are we expecting in this function? The error trapping and the error message seem to be entirely pointless.

Comment: @RoobieNuby That's just my default error handling. I put it in on all my functions because if something goes wrong, I want the staff to call me, not to try and fix it themselves.

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't really want to do this given the existing Instr/InstrRev functions but there are times when it is handy to use EVALUATE to return the result of Excel worksheet functions within VBA

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Debug.Print ContainsSubString("bc", "abc,d")

End Sub
Public Function ContainsSubString(ByVal substring As String, ByVal testString As String) As Boolean
    'substring = string to test for; testString = string to search
    ContainsSubString = Evaluate("=ISNUMBER(FIND(" & Chr$(34) & substring & Chr$(34) & ", " & Chr$(34) & testString & Chr$(34) & "))")

End Function
```

Comment: Fyi - maybe interested in further late post getting also match positions :+) @Harr

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the possibilities listed, I would like to demonstrate how you can use **`Split()`** for an all-round function with the following variants depending on the optional argument `n` passed:

- a) show whether a substring was found at all (-1 or omitted as default value)
- b) show how many substrings were found (0) ,
- c) show at which position the nth substring was found (1 .. n).

```
Function StrIncludes( _
      ByVal s As String, _
      Optional ByVal IncludeString As String = ",", _
      Optional n As Long = -1 _
    ) As Long
'Purp.: find specified substring based on numeric value n
'Note : 2nd argument IncludeString is optional (default value is comma if omitted)
'       3rd argument n:  -1~~>only boolean; 0~~>count(s); 1..n ~~>position
    Dim tmp: tmp = Split(s, IncludeString)
    StrIncludes = UBound(tmp) > 0           ' a) boolean return value indicating a found substring
    
    Select Case n                           ' individual numeric values:
        Case 0                              ' b) return Count(s), not boolean value
            StrIncludes = UBound(tmp)
        Case 1
            StrIncludes = IIf(StrIncludes, Len(tmp(n - 1)) + n, 0)
        Case Is > 1                        ' c) return Position of nth finding
            If n > UBound(tmp) Then StrIncludes = 0: Exit Function
            StrIncludes = IIf(StrIncludes, Len(tmp(0)) + n, 0)
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 2 To n: StrIncludes = StrIncludes + Len(tmp(i - 1)): Next
    End Select
End Function
```

**Example call**

```
Sub ExampleCall()
'   define base string
    Dim s As String
    s = "Take this example string, does it contain a comma, doesn't it?"
'a) check if base string contains indicated search string, e.g. a comma (default value)
    Debug.Print "Is Found: " & CBool(StrIncludes(s)) ' ~~> Is Found: True
'b) get number of substrings
    Debug.Print "Count(s): " & StrIncludes(s, , 0)   ' ~~> Count(s): 2
'c) get position of nth substring
    Debug.Print "~~~ Findings of nth substring ~~~ "
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print n & ordinalSuffix(n) & " substring at Pos.:  " & StrIncludes(s, , n)
    Next
End Sub
```

```
Function ordinalSuffix(ByVal number As Long) As String
    Dim suffixes: suffixes = Split(" st nd rd th")
    ordinalSuffix = suffixes(Abs(number))
End Function
```

**Debugging results in immediate window**

```
Is Found: Wahr
Count(s): 2
~~~ Findings of nth substring ~~~ 
1st substring at Pos.:  25
2nd substring at Pos.:  50
3rd substring at Pos.:  0  ' no finding at all
```