# How to find cells that contain specific text then hide the entire row

Tags: vba, excel, hide, document

When a button is pressed I want to loop through all the cells in my Sheet and find the cells that contains .doc or .xls or .pdf and hide the entire Row.
I know I can't use `Contains` but there must be something similar.

Cell example `PM-TR Training.doc`

This is what I have for now what can I replace contains with?

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim DataCount As Integer
    'Change the sheet name as necessary in the following line
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        DataCount = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & DataCount)
            If cell.Contains(".doc") Or cell.Contains(".xls") Or cell.Contains(".pdf") Then
                'The following code assumes you want the row hidden.
                Range(cell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a string contains another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585058/check-if-a-string-contains-another-string)

Comment: I saw this question before posting but I didn't really understand how to make it work for my case. Now I do thanks to user3561813

Comment: You could have mentioned it in your question in order to get a better help on the implentation, but the important thing is that you understand now

Comment: I will make sure to do it next time, thank you.

Comment: Would an autofilter work? Why use VBA for this?

Comment: I don't think so, I have a button to hide the links to documents and another button to show them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function InStr withing your `IF` statement should do the trick.

```
IF instr(cell.value, ".doc")> 0 then
    'Code Here
```