# i need to fix this line it says object required: If FullName.Contains(",") Then

Tags: vba

i need to fix this line it says object required:
If FullName.Contains(",") Then

This is my code:

```
Private Sub retrieveinput_Click()
     FullName = inputText.Text
     Dim NameArray() As String

     If FullName.Contains(",") Then
         NameArray = Split(FullName, ",")
         First = NameArray(1)
         Last = NameArray(0)
     Else
         NameArray = Split(FullName)
         First = NameArray(0)
         Last = NameArray(1)
     End If

     TextBox2.Text = First
     TextBox3.Text = Last

End Sub
```

Comment: okay thanks for that edit, but i still get the error in vba excel on the same line: If FullName.Contains(",") Then

Comment: Is this VBA or VB.NET?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this:

```
Dim foo As String
foo = "foobar"

If foo.Contains("bar") Then
...
```

This isn't VB.NET, strings aren't objects in VBA, so there's no `Contains` method to call. The VBA way of doing this is to use the `InStr` function, like this:

```
If InStr(FullName, ",") > 0 Then
```

See this post: [Check if a string contains another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585058/check-if-a-string-contains-another-string)

You could also make yourself a helper function like this:

```
Public Function Contains(ByVal string_source As String, ByVal find_text As String, Optional ByVal caseSensitive As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim compareMethod As VbCompareMethod

    If caseSensitive Then
        compareMethod = vbBinaryCompare
    Else
        compareMethod = vbTextCompare
    End If

    Contains = (InStr(1, string_source, find_text, compareMethod) <> 0)

End Function
```

And then you could do

```
If Contains(FullName, ",") Then
```

Answer (score -1):

An error such as 'Object required' usually means that you have missed an assignment somewhere. In this case if the error is on the line

```
If FullName.Contains(",") Then
```

then FullName is null or hasn't been defined. This may be because of the following:

1. inputText is not a variable or control
2. Text is not a property or method of inputText
3. inputText.Text value is null

First thing to check in these circumstances is if the variable you are trying top access has a value (i.e. not null)

Comment: it worked for the else statement before i made my if statement.  I put my name into the text, hit my button and it split the name into two other text boxes but when using the comma it does not work

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the line with the error - then check the value of inputText.Text. As mentioned before, ensure that Dim FullName is before use in your method ( or in scope outside).

Comment: i literally know nothing about this, it was thrown at me and am not a CS major

Comment: Click in the margin on the left of the line (a red circle should appear) or select the line and press F9, or right-click the line and select breakpoint - there are many ways to do this depending on the environment you are using. Then run it in debug mode and the program will pause execution at the breakpoint.

Comment: got that besides run in debug mode? i ran it normally while it was red and nothing different happened

Comment: What's the environment? Excel? Word? Web?

Comment: also just did something and said breakpoint not allowed on this line

Comment: excel vba using macros

Comment: If the code is EXACTLY as you have above, then change it to be:
Dim FullName As String
FullName = inputText.Text (two lines)

Comment: it is exactly as above

Comment: thanks for all the help i got it with this: InStr(FullName,",")