# InSTR or find function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck with an issue. I've done my research and found out that I can use InSTR function to search for a specific character in a string.

What I am trying to do is get a file name extracted from a file path.

Currently I have

```
  InStr(StrFrom(pName), "\")
```

The issue here is, it returns the first occurrence of slash, where as I want to get the last occurrence of the slash (so that I can use a 'right' function wrapped around the above code to capture the file name)

Any help is appreciated on how to get the last slash in a string!

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string contains another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585058/check-if-a-string-contains-another-string)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Instr` looks from the start of the text string, `InstrRev` starts looking from the other end.

```
Public Function FileNameOnly(ByVal FileNameAndPath As String) As String

    FileNameOnly = Mid(FileNameAndPath, InStrRev(FileNameAndPath, "\") + 1, Len(FileNameAndPath))

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks all - I've used a combination about instrRev + above logic to get the name :)

Comment: Was going to add `MsgBox CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFileName(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName("<Full Path To File>"))` as a one liner - not particularly useful though (calls the FileSystemObject twice). :)

Comment: both fine solutions to which I'd add 1) use `Application.PathSeparator` instead of `"\"` and give it more generality 2)  avoid double FileSystemObject objects `With CreateObject "Scripting.FileSystemObject")|  FileNameOnly = .GetFileName(.GetAbsolutePathName(FileNameAndPath))| End With -`

Comment: `Application.PathSeparator` - that was the command I was trying to remember.  Couldn't think of the wording to save my life. :)

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim s As String, ary
    s = "C:\whatever\sub1\sub2\reallydeep\x.xlsm"
    ary = Split(s, "\")
    MsgBox ary(UBound(ary))
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use InStrRev() to find the first occurrence of the slash from the right side of the string.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2ekk41a(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming StrFrom is some user defined function, the following will do what you want:

```
Dim filename as String
Dim path as String

path = StrFrom(pName)
filename = Mid$(path, InstrRev(path, "\") + 1)
```

Note that its easier to use Mid$ than Right$, as InstrRev returns the character position from the left of the string. Omitting the final parameter of Mid$, returns the rest of the string from that position.