# What is the ".*" equivalent of Java in Visual Basic for Excel?

Tags: string, vba

In Java, we can use the string.matches(" .* anytext .* ") to see if the string contains the string 'anytext' in it, how does one do the same in Visual Basic for Excel?

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Like` operator together with the the wildcard symbol `*`:

```
MyString Like "*anytext*"
```

will return true if and only if `MyString` contains `"anytext"`.

See [this](http://analystcave.com/vba-like-operator/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Instr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264811%28v=office.14%29.aspx) function

```
Dim pos As Integer

pos = InStr("find the comma, in the string", ",")
```

will return 15 in pos

If not found it will return 0

If you need to find the comma with an excel formula you can use the `=FIND(",";A1)` function.

Notice that if you want to use `Instr` to find the position of a string case-insensitive use the third parameter of `Instr` and give it the const `vbTextCompare` (or just 1 for die-hards).

```
Dim posOf_A As Integer

posOf_A = InStr(1, "find the comma, in the string", "A", vbTextCompare)
```

will give you a value of 14.

Note that you have to specify the start position in this case as stated in the specification I linked: The start argument is required if compare is specified.

Answer in : [Check if a string contains another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585058/check-if-a-string-contains-another-string)