# VBA Selecting specific sheets then copypaste specific cell

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to write a macro that loops through the pages within a workbook, and anything that contains `DR` the name of the sheet should be put to sheet `Macro` and a content of a cell.

```
Sub FnGetSheetsName()
    Dim mainworkBook As Workbook

    Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook

    For i = 1 To mainworkBook.Sheets.Count
        If mainworkBook.Sheets.Name.Contains("DR") Then
            mainworkBook.Sheets("Macro").Range("A" & i) = mainworkBook.Sheets.Name
            mainworkBook.Sheets("Macro").Range("B" & i) = mainworkBook.Sheets.Range("B17")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

It stops at: `If mainworkBook.Sheets.Name.Contains("DR")` Then

Thanks for your answers! :)
Tibor

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `Like` method:

`If mainworkBook.Sheets.Name Like "*DR*" Then` instead of the line that causes problems.

Another option would be:

`If InStr(1, mainworkBook.Sheets.Name, "DR", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then`

InStr will return the position that the text has been found or zero if it's not found.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out, in your code, you're writing this :

> ```
> mainworkBook.Sheets.Name.Contains ...
> ```

Or this :

> ```
> mainworkBook.Sheets.Range("B17")
> ```

Nevertheless, mainworkBook.Sheets is a variable that contains all your sheets.
In order to test the name of just one sheet, you should write :

`mainworkBook.Sheets(Integer).Name.Contains ...`

I didn't know about the "Contains" function, so I used [InStr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585058/check-if-a-string-contains-another-string)

```
For i = 1 To mainworkBook.Sheets.Count
    If InStr(mainworkBook.Sheets(i).Name, "DR") <> 0 Then
        mainworkBook.Sheets("Macro").Range("A" & i) = mainworkBook.Sheets(i).Name
        mainworkBook.Sheets("Macro").Range("B" & i) = mainworkBook.Sheets(i).Range("B17")
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
Sub nnh()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 0

    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If Sheet.Name Like "DB*" Then 
            x = x + 1
            Sheets("Macro").Range("A" & x) = Sheet.Name
            Sheets("Macro").Range("B" & x) = Sheets(Sheet.Name).Range("B17")
        End If
    Next Sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Because the number of sheets within a workbook is unlimited ([only limited by available memory](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3)) you should dim `x` as `Long` instead of `Integer`. Always use `Long` instead of `Interger` **unless** you need to Interop with an old API call that expects a 16 bit int. Read more about [Integer and Long?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613).