# Replace Bold Font with html bold tags around text

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to create Excel VBA code to find bold text and add html bold tags around the found text.

Example:
Find: "This **bold** word" and
Replace with: "This **`<b>bold</b>`** word" (both html tags and word need to be bold)

Note: the bold text is within cells with non bold text and only the bold text should be replaced.

I also need to convert the other way. Meaning find bold tags (`<b></b>`) with or without bold font itself and remove the tags and ensure the text is bold.

Found [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=57419) which seems close, but I have an issue with `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select` and `.Wrap = wdFindStop`.

I also found [this](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/524889-find-replace-loses-text-properties-formatting.html) which may help to find/replace text without losing bold formatting, but not exactly what I need. This may be overkill for what I am looking to do.

I have something in the works.

```
Sub removeboldaddHtml()
    lastrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        msg = ""
        For j = 1 To Len(Cells(i, 1))
            If Range("A" & i).Characters(j, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
                msg = msg & Mid(Cells(i, 1), j, 1)
            End If
        Next j ' next character
        If msg <> "" Then
            Cells(i, "B").Value = "<b>" & msg & "</b>"
        End If
    Next i ' next row
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you working in Excel or Word ?

Comment: I think regex might be helpful, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You will need to loop over the cell's Characters collection and check each character to see where the bold formatting begins and ends.  It will  not be simple if you're adding/removing "<b></b>" as you go, since you'll have to keep adjusting the index as you add/remove.

Comment: Robin, Trying to create Excel VBA Macro to find/replace text within another excel.

Comment: Tim, do you have any examples you can provide me?

Comment: I found this https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/524889-find-replace-loses-text-properties-formatting.html, but not sure how I can tweak to find Bold Text instead of specific text?

Comment: @MichaelKapp Please accept an answer if it fit your needs. Thats the way to say "thank you" in this site (where you get help for free). Tim's answer seems to elegantly fulfill your first requirement....

Answer (score 2):

Following code is rather crude, inelegant, and resource-consuming. But may help anyway (for the first part of your question). It will work only if bold is continous (It won't work **for** something **like** this). Data is in sheet "Sheet1", column A (only rows 1 to 3 in the following code). **Edited** to get tags and text between tags in bold.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim MyStringLength  As Integer
    Dim OriginalString As String
    Dim MyRow As Long
    Dim StartPos As Integer
    Dim EndPos As Integer


        For MyRow = 1 To 3 'Adjust to your row number
            StartPos = 0
            EndPos = 0
            MyStringLenght = Len(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(MyRow, 1))
            For i = 1 To MyStringLenght
                If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(MyRow, 1).Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
                    If StartPos = 0 Then
                        StartPos = i
                    End If
                    EndPos = i
                End If
            Next
            OriginalString = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(MyRow, 1)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(MyRow, 2) = StartPos
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(MyRow, 3) = EndPos
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(MyRow, 4) = Left(OriginalString, StartPos - 1) & "<b>" & Mid(OriginalString, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos + 1) & "</b>" & Right(OriginalString, MyStringLenght - EndPos)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(MyRow, 4).Characters(StartPos, EndPos - StartPos + 7).Font.Bold = True
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I thought I was clear. I NEED to replace bold font within cells with Non Bold font. I also could not get your macro to work.

Comment: 1) In your question you stated that "both html tags and word need to be bold". If you don't want the replacement to be bold, just delete the line `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(MyRow, 4).Characters(StartPos, EndPos - StartPos + 7).Font.Bold = True`. 2) The macro is working for me. Perhaps you can add details of which line is not working (stepping the code with F8 maybe).

Comment: Another Ex. Replace: "Some random example **text** within a cell" with:     "Some random example **<b>text</b>** within a cell".        I need the word "text" and the html tags to be bold after the replace.  This is the line that does not work:
    Worksheets("test").Cells(MyRow, 4) = Left(OriginalString, StartPos - 1) & "<b>" & Mid(OriginalString, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos + 1) & "</b>" & Right(OriginalString, MyStringLenght - EndPos)

Comment: Thats what the full code is supposed to do. Do you have the sample text in the first row? If cell is empty code will fail (no handling errors). And of course the posted code is not replacing, but writing the output in another column (#4)...

Comment: Got the code you provided above to work. Not sure why it did not work for me initially. Thanks for your time on this. Any recommendation on going the other way? Meaning html tags to no html, but keep/add bold between where there was html tags?

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark as accepted...! And about the other way, I'm in a rush right now (no time to write the code), but I think you can use [InStr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15585089/1726522). That function finds a substring in a string (`<b>` and `</b>` in your case) and returns the position. Once you know the position, add Bold to the characters in between (similar to the last line of my code) and then delete the three characters to the left or the right.

Answer (score 2):

Example for adding tags:

```
Sub Tester()
    AddTags Range("A1")
End Sub

Sub AddTags(c As Range)

    Dim p As Long, isB As Boolean
    Do
        p = p + 1
        If p > Len(c.Value) Then Exit Do

        If c.Characters(p, 1).Font.Bold And Not isB Then
            'entering a bolded section
            c.Characters(p, 0).Insert "<b>"
            c.Characters(p, 3).Font.Bold = True
            isB = True
            p = p + 3 'skip the tag you just added
        ElseIf Not c.Characters(p, 1).Font.Bold And isB Then
            'leaving a bolded section
            c.Characters(p, 0).Insert "</b>"
            c.Characters(p, 4).Font.Bold = True
            isB = False
            p = p + 4 'skip the tag you just added
        End If
    Loop
    'close any open tag
    If isB Then c.Characters(p, 0).Insert "</b>"
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice! Shorter, clearer, and **will** work on non **continuous** bold words.

Comment: So this worked great for small demos, but when I try to feed it a range (Range("C2:D50"))  it breaks. I tried using a For each box in Range loop as well, but the code will either hang or it will perform some weird changes like putting each letter in a new line within the cell. Sometimes it just skips bolded text. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see what you tried, so I have no useful suggestions.  Would be best to post a new question with your current code, a description of exactly what's not working, and a link back to this post.

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812463/adding-html-tags-based-on-font-does-not-work-on-all-cells