# Regular Expression Pattern for Full Match of Filenames

Tags: regex, excel, vba, pattern-matching, multiple-matches

I am looping through an Array of Image Filenames which are as below:

1. ConImage1 - Core.png
2. ConImage211 - Core.png
3. ConImage34 - Core.png
4. ConImage09 - Core.png
5. ConImage11 - Core.png
6. ConImageOri23.png
7. ConImageOri2.png
8. ConImageOri11.png
9. ConImageOri132.png
10. ConImageForEng7 - Core.png
11. ConImageForEng12 - Core.png
12. ConImageForEng11 - Core.png
13. ConImageForEng10 - Core.png
14. ConImage1-Dislikes-Core.png
15. ConImage1-Likes-Core.png
16. ConImage12 - Dislikes - Core.png
17. ConImage12 - Likes - Core.png
18. ConImage34 - Dislikes - Core.png
19. ConImage34 - Likes - Core.png
20. ConImage55 - Dislikes - Core.png
21. ConImage55 - Likes - Core.png

I need a Regex pattern that will only match the following Filenames:

1. ConImage1 - Core.png
2. ConImage211 - Core.png
3. ConImage34 - Core.png
4. ConImage09 - Core.png
5. ConImage11 - Core.png
6. ConImageOri23.png
7. ConImageOri2.png
8. ConImageOri11.png
9. ConImageOri132.png

and exclude the filenames containing the words : Likes, Dislikes, ForEng etc.

**Edit:**

I am not good at regex but trying something like this to limit my search.

```
^(ConImage|(Orig|!ForEng)){1}[0-9\ \-]+[\W(Dislikes|Likes)][0-9\ \-]+(Core\.png)$/i/g
```

OR the below works for finding necessary files, but if some odd name comes out e.g. ConImageMaxx12 - Core.png etc, it also picks that up.

```
^ConImage((?!ForEng|Dislikes|Likes).)*$
```

I don't want to implement VBA.Filter function but need a Regex solution.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply use `InStr`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585058/check-if-a-string-contains-another-string/15585089)?

Comment: Remove `/i/g`, VBA regex does not support regex literal notation. There are special options, `RegEx.Global = True`, `RegEx.IgnoreCase = True` etc.

Comment: @npinti i am using regex in my code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes i know. just put it there to indicate i need case-insensitive matches.

Comment: You could always just use `Filter` function on your array instead, excluding those that have any of those words in their string.

Comment: So is there no regular expression pattern to find the given filenames without resorting to VBA functions? From the comments, can i assume that it is not possible?

Comment: *there no regular expression pattern to find the given filenames without resorting to VBA functions* - true, if you do not want to use VBA functions, you do not need any regex, since you won't be able to use it.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this to limit my search.`^ConImage((?!ForEng|Dislikes|Likes).)*(.png){1}$`. This works well for finding necessary files, but if some odd name comes out e.g. `ConImageMaxx12 - Core.png` etc, it also picks that up.

Comment: Might be useful to update your question with the actual code you're trying (so that anyone who wants to help out doesn't have to write/find it themselves), along with the actual regex pattern: the one you posted is not the one you tried, so that may have put some folk off....

Comment: How do you expect to use Regex in Excel without using VBA?

Comment: What are your specific rules?  `exclude Likes, Dislikes, ForEng etc ` is not really specific enough for a computer due to the **etc**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specific rules, it is hard to come up with a regex.
To match the specific values you have posted (and exclude the `ConImageMaxx12` you mentioned in a comment), you could try:

**Edit** to correct the missing "Start of String" token

```
^ConImage(?:Ori)?\d+(?:(?!(?:For|Likes)).)*$
```

That regex matches:

- `ConImage`
- optionally matches `Ori`
- matches one or more digits
- and then matches the rest of the string so long as it does not contain the substrings in the negative lookahead (which would include `ForEng`, `Likes`, `Dislikes` and other derivatives)

Whether that set of rules is sufficient to eliminate the unwanted file names cannot be stated, since I am only guessing at some rules based on what you've written.

Here is a more formal explanation of the Regex with some links to a tutorial explanation:

Note that, in accordance with your comments, we set the case-insensitive option

### Match Specific File Names

```
^ConImage(?:Ori)?\d+(?:(?!(?:For|Likes)).)*$
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Assert position at the beginning of a line](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`
- [Match the character string “ConImage” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `ConImage`
- [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:Ori)?`

  - [Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) `?`
  - [Match the character string “Ori” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Ori`
- [Match a single character that is a “digit”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:(?!(?:For|Likes)).)*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!(?:For|Likes))`

    - [Match the regular expression below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(?:For|Likes)`

      - [Match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `For`

        - [Match the character string “For” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `For`
      - [Or match this alternative](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `Likes`

        - [Match the character string “Likes” literally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `Likes`
  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.`
- [Assert position at the end of a line](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$`

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: Thanks Ron. Since it works with the above 5 types of filenames found in a folder, I only changed the above pattern slightly `^ConImage(?:Ori)?\d+(?:(?!(?:ForEng|Likes|Dislikes)).)*$`. Is this correct? I am getting full matches.

Comment: @sifar Based on the information you have provided, **No**.  The regex I provided worked on the information you provided, and making it more complex was not indicated.  Was there some problem with the original, so far as matching was concerned?  Was it filtering out files that should have been matched?

Comment: For example you have used `For` instead of `ForEng` and `Dislikes` and `^` were missing, so got confused.

Comment: @sifar The `^` missing is a typo and should have been included (I will edit my answer)..  But your other changes unnecessarily add a comparison operation.

Comment: Understood now. Appreciate your guidance.